# Bool Vector realization

Tags: c++, vector, boolean

Can somebody tell me how this vector actually works? Particularly about its `operator=` and `operator bool` of `VecProxy` class and `operator[]` of main class. I understand that it is needed for reduce the amount of memory used. Like bool is 1 byte and with this class we can reduce it by 7 bits for every element. I guess `VecProxy` needed for distribution every bit to its place.

So, here is the code:

```
template <>
class Vector<bool>
{
private:
    typedef unsigned char byte;
    size_t _size;
    size_t _capacity;
    size_t _byte_size;
    byte* _data;
public:
    Vector(size_t capacity = 0) : _size(0),
        _capacity(capacity),
        _byte_size(0),
        _data(nullptr)
    {
        if (capacity > 0)
        {
            _data = new byte[capacity / 8 + (capacity % 8 != 0)];
            if (!_data) throw "Out of memory";
        }
    }

    class VecProxy
    {
        size_t _idx;
        byte* _vec_ptr;
    public:
        VecProxy(size_t idx, byte* vecPtr) : _idx(idx), _vec_ptr(vecPtr) {}
        VecProxy& operator=(bool val)
        {
            size_t char_idx = _idx / 8;
            size_t bit_idx = _idx % 8;
            if (val)
                _vec_ptr[char_idx] |= 1 << bit_idx;
            else
                _vec_ptr[char_idx] &= ~(1 << bit_idx);
            return *this;
        }

        operator bool()
        {
            size_t char_idx = _idx / 8;
            size_t bit_idx = _idx % 8;
            return (_vec_ptr[char_idx] >> char_idx) & 0x01;
        }
    };

    VecProxy operator[](size_t idx)
    {
        if (idx >= _size) throw "Out of bounds";
        return VecProxy(idx, _data);
    }

    Vector& resize(size_t new_size)
    {
        _capacity = new_size;
        _size = _capacity < _size ? _capacity : _size;
        _byte_size = _size / 8 + (_size % 8 != 0);
        byte* tmp = new byte[_capacity / 8 + (_capacity % 8 != 0)];
        if (!tmp) throw "Out of memory";
        for (size_t i = 0; i < _byte_size; ++i)
            tmp[i] = _data[i];
        if (!_data)
            delete[] _data;
        _data = tmp;
    }

    Vector& push_back(bool val)
    {
        if (_size == _capacity)
        {
            if (_capacity < 10)
                resize(_capacity + 10);
            else
                resize(_capacity * 1.5);
        }
        VecProxy(_size++, _data) = val;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

It must be a bit confusing that I have `template<>`. But in other part of `.h` file placed the main realization of standard `vector`.

So, I want to specify my question:

1. What actually is going on in `operator=` in `VecProxy` class? I am very confused about that `if`.
2. The `return` statement of `operator bool()` is unclear.
3. But I actually get an idea of `operator[]`.

Comment: I'm unsure what your question is, like what it is you don't understand. _"Can somebody tell me how this vector actually works?"_ is such a broad question you'd have to write a book to cover everything.

Comment: I actually said about operator=, operator[] and operator bool, I ll write a bit more distinctly

Comment: Do you understand the bit packing that is going on?

Comment: @user4581301 No

Comment: `bool is 1 byte and with this class we can reduce it by 7 bits for every element.` you seem to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From

> Like bool is 1 byte and with this class we can reduce it by 7 bits for every element.

We know that you understand that each bit has distinct meaning, each representing a different boolean value, and that these bits are then *packed* together into a byte to save space.

In order to get the boolean value back out again, you have to locate the correct byte and then the bit in that byte. `_vec_ptr[char_idx]` finds the correct byte. `1 << bit_idx` produces a [*bit mask*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)) that isolates the bit.

Lets look at `VecProxy`'s `operator=` a bit closer:

```
    VecProxy& operator=(bool val)
    {
        size_t char_idx = _idx / 8; // find byte index
        size_t bit_idx = _idx % 8; // find bit index
        if (val) // boolean is true, so bit must be set to 1
            _vec_ptr[char_idx] |= 1 << bit_idx;
        else // boolean false, so bit must be set to 0
            _vec_ptr[char_idx] &= ~(1 << bit_idx);
        return *this;
    }
```

Lets split the function up a bit more:

```
    VecProxy& operator=(bool val)
    {
        size_t char_idx = _idx / 8; // find byte index
        size_t bit_idx = _idx % 8; // find bit index
        byte & loc = _vec_ptr[char_idx]; // reference to byte that must be updated
        byte mask = 1 << bit_idx; // mask isolating bit that must be updated

        if (val) // boolean is true, so bit must be set to 1
            loc |= mask;
        else // boolean false, so bit must be set to 0
            loc &= ~(mask);
        return *this;
    }
```

If the `bool` provided, `val` is true, then the bit needs to be a 1. This is pretty easy, you just OR in the bit mask. Say we want the third bit

```
00000100
```

and we have

```
10101010
```

Apply OR

```
10101010 OR 00000100 = 10101110
```

But if the value is false, we need to set the bit to zero We can't do that with OR, but we can with AND. Unfortunately if you do that trivially you get

```
11111111 AND 00000000 = 00000000
```

And that's useless. You want to keep the other bits. You need to invert the mask

```
11111111 AND 11111011 = 11111011
```

And that's what the `~` operator is doing in `loc &= ~(mask);`

As it turns out, the assignment operator is next to useless. The only way to get a `VecProxy`is through

```
VecProxy operator[](size_t idx)
```

and it returns by value. It can't be used to set a bit in the `Vector`. You can set a bit in the proxy, and that's it. This change cannot be propagated through to `Vector`.

```
myvec[42] = true;
```

fails to compile because it would be updating a temporary copy.

Returning a `VecProxy` by reference so that the `vector` can be updated is a non-trivial rewrite.

Now lets look at operator bool

```
    operator bool()
    {
        size_t char_idx = _idx / 8;
        size_t bit_idx = _idx % 8;
        return (_vec_ptr[char_idx] >> char_idx) & 0x01;
    }
```

This function tells you whether or not the bit represented by this proxy object is set or not. How it does it: We find the byte with `_vec_ptr[char_idx]` then we shift the whole byte over to bring the bit of interest into the first bit and mask off everything but the bit of interest. If that one bit is set, return true.

Say we start with

```
10101010
```

and we want the third bit:

```
10101010 >> 2 == 00101010
```

(Note! watch out for sign extension! If byte is unsigned you'll get `11101010` to keep the number negative. Doesn't matter here, but it will get you in other circumstances.)

now we use the mask 0x01 (`00000001`) to check if the bit is set.

```
00101010 & 00000001 = 00000000
```

C++ handles it from there converting 0 into a return of `false`